# Dispose, Clear widget from screen and memory in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to dispose a StatefulWidget class object (containing GestureDetector in my case) in flutter using dispose() and also remove it from the screen afterwards when it's clicked. It's object needs to be deleted and cleared from screen (and not just hidden using some variable)

```dart
.
.
.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => setState(() {
          if (mounted) {
            dispose();
          }
        }),
        child: Container(...),
      );
}
.
.
```

But since dispose() doesn't remove it from screen just release memory, it still is on screen. For some reason, it still gets clicked and calls setState (which it shouldn't technically since its already disposed) hence giving error :-

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════
═════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a
gesture:
setState() called after dispose():
_EnemyState#cc989(lifecycle state: defunct)        
This error happens if you call setState() on a     
State object for a widget that no longer appears in
the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no      
longer includes the widget in its build). This     
error
can occur when code calls setState() from a timer  
or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or   
stop listening to the animation in the dispose()   
callback. Another solution is to check the
"mounted" property of this object before calling   
setState() to ensure the object is still in the    
tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if
setState() is being called because another object  
is
retaining a reference to this State object after it
has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory    
leaks, consider breaking the reference to this     
object during dispose().
```

Also, is there any way to be sure there are no memory leaks after dispose() getting called? Because it seems there are leaks since the app's memory usage keeps on increasing as I create many object of the class but also dispose them regularly.

Tried printing value of mounted but it gives true both before and after disposing, maybe I'm disposing it the wrong way.

Comment: What do you mean by "dispose" the GestureDetector? Do you want to keep its child but make it not clickable anymore, or do you want to remove both the GestureDetector and its child altogether? And after this disposal, do you want the user to continue at the same screen or it would go back to the previous one?

Comment: @enzo here's what it looks like - The GestureDetector and its child is in a separate StatefulWidget in separate dart file, and its just a widget, not a page that I'm importing to main.dart. I've created that class's object in main.dart (which i guess is why its "retaining a reference" to object even after it gets disposed and still appear on screen). I want to dispose both GestureDetector and its child, delete them from memory as well as screen upon clicking, which apparently doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you rebuild the Widget tree without a certain Widget, it automatically gets disposed and removed.

For example, say this is in the StatefulWidget inside your `main.dart`:

```
// State. We have a gesture detector by default
bool hasGestureDetector = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final container = Container(
    color: Colors.purple,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  );
  final button = OutlinedButton(
    // Tapping the button will toggle the boolean and rebuild the Widget, 
    // enabling/disabling the gesture detector
    onPressed: () => setState(() => hasGestureDetector = !hasGestureDetector),
    child: Text('Toggle Gesture Detector'),
  );

  return Column(
    children: [
      // Either render the container directly, or wrap it in a gesture detector, 
      // depending on the current state
      if (hasGestureDetector)
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: ...,
          child: container,
        )
      else
        container,
      button,
    ],
  );
}
```

When you tap the button, the Widget rebuilds, and the GestureDetector is either removed or re-added. `dispose` is called by Flutter, so there's no need to call it yourself for Widget classes (this is different for things like `Controller`s for text editing, see [the dispose method here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#create-a-texteditingcontroller).

Comment: I didn't know hiding the widget using condition not only hides but also disposes it, thanks. Does this mean we never need to explicitly call dispose() ever and Flutter does everything on its own?

Comment: For standard Widgets that are in the Widget tree, mostly yes. Exceptions exist for longer-lived variables like the `TextEditingController` mentioned at the bottom of my answer or a manually created `ScrollController` that lives in the state of a `StatefulWidget`

Comment: As a test, you can create your own `StatefulWidget` with a print statement in the `initState` and `dispose` methods. As you add and remove this Widget from the tree, it should call these methods

Comment: Is there any way to create many objects of a StatefulWidget which get dispose on some condition and individual ones getting cleared. I've tried but it doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can give the parent widget a `List` or a `Map` of Widgets, and add/remove them as required. But at that point, why not just have some objects/classes in the (parent) state, and create Widgets in `build`? That way, you'll never have Widgets that are not in the Widget tree taking up space